# Draw DAG graphs in JSF

Tags: jsf, graph

I need to draw a DAG graph (i.e. graph with node and directed edges) in a JSF page.
Could anyone suggest me a library to do this??
I prefer a JAVA library because the graph is generated dynamically from database data, so I will implements a Bean to design the graph and after show it in a JSF page.

N.B. I use Primefaces, for notice

Comment: JSF in the end will generate plain HTML. It's **your work** (not ours) to search how can you handle this. *I prefer a JAVA library because...* please read the FAQ: [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Come back when you have a real question.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this primefaces component for jsf: [Primefaces MindMap Component](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/mindmap.jsf)

Or check opensource jgrapht. [Example Here](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/visualizations.html)

Or I strongly suggest to check this javascript library to generate your own graphs: [rapgael js library](http://raphaeljs.com/)

You can generate directed acyclic graph with both of them. 
Good luck!

Comment: I can't use MindMap because it has a root node and some node related to it, but I need a graph with nodes at the same level, with directed edges among them. The number of the nodes and the edges is get from a database, so the generation of the graph has to be dynamical.

Comment: Take a look this [link](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/visualizations.html), this is what you need i think?